# confused in using ON or Open

Tags: word-choice

I would like to send a circular to parents which mentions that the school will be open on an off day due to a function. What should be the sentence that I should write?

1. The school will be ON
2. The school will be open

or advice sentence instead of these sentences?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular sent to parents by school](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/347603/circular-sent-to-parents-by-school)